# How to make case insensitive constraints?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

How do I make a case insensitive constraint on a varchar. So if I inserted the same `dob` but the name's where `bob` and `Bob` they would be considered as duplicates?

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
  name varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  dob date NOT NULL,
  
  CONSTRAINT test_uq UNIQUE (LOWER(name), dob)
);

INSERT INTO customer (name, dob) VALUES('bob', '01/01/2020'); // This would work
INSERT INTO customer (name, dob) VALUES('Bob', '01/01/2020'); // This would not work because its a duplicate even though it Bob and not bob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the column with a case-insensitive collation:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
  name varchar(32) collate utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  dob date NOT NULL,
  unique (name, dob)
);
```

By default MySQL is case-insensitive, so I assume your server or database has set the collation to a case-sensitive collation.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8156f94dc6a3ee114f63904c248411e5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Can you explain collate utf8mb4_general_ci

Comment: @Paul . . . That forces the collation of the column to be case-insensitive -- which is what you want.  The topic of collations is complicated, but a place to start is the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-syntax.html.